# Display max value of a dimension in a numberDisplay dc.js

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have a csv file with temperatures for several cities with this format:

```
city    maxTemp
Vienna  25.5
Prague  24.4
Paris   24.3
Berlin  23.3
Athens  33.1
```

I'm creating a dashboard and I would like to show in a `numberDisplay` the maximum temperature from the cities filtered (when clicking other **DC.js** charts).

I have managed to get the maximum value from the dimension, but I can't manage to make it change when the cities are filtered and I don't know what group and `valueAccessor` should I use to display the maximum temperature in the `numberDisplay`. How do I solve this problem?

**Here is what I've tried:**

```
function show_avg_temp(ndx,element) {

   var maxTempDim = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck('maxTemp'));

   maxMaxTemp = maxTempDim.top(1)[0].maxTemp;

   console.log(maxMaxTemp);

   dc.numberDisplay(element)
      .group(??)
      .valueAccessor(??)
      .formatNumber(d3.format('.2'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### A little context

One confusing thing about the `numberDisplay` is that it works best with a [groupAll object](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_groupAll) but it also works with a regular group (with some difficulty).

We recently added methods to clarify similar problems with the `dataTable` and `dataCount`, and [I opened an issue to do the same with `numberDisplay`](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1525).

Anyway, that's still not quite what you need, since [there is no efficient way to compute a min or max with a group or groupAll](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/issues/25). The obvious way to reduce a maximum is to see if each added value is greater than the current max, but in order to remove, you basically need everything sorted.

#### A solution

So, long story short, and as you know already: what you're doing is basically right but you need a way to feed that live number to the `numberDisplay`.

Easiest way is to fake the `.value()` function that a groupAll object would have, and also tell the `numberDisplay` that a value is just a value:

```
function dim_max_groupAll(dim, field) {
  return {
    value: function() {
      return dim.top(1)[0][field];
    }
  };
}
numberDisplay
  .group(dim_max_groupAll(maxTempDim, 'maxTemp'))
  .valueAccessor(x => x);
```

This "fake groupAll" ensures that whenever the `numberDisplay` is redrawn, the fresh top value will be taken from the dimension.

Comment: @Elena, did this work? I didn't test it but similar questions have come up before (probably belongs in a FAQ or example somewhere).

Comment: Hi Gordon, yes it worked!! I wasn't able to test it until now and that is why I didn't answer before. Thanks a lot!! :)